# If I Uninstall Data.com Will I Lose The Contacts We Added Using the Program?

Tags: data.com, uninstall

If I delete Data.com will I lose the contacts that we added through the package?

It has been inactive for years and is taking up custom fields that I need to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not. You'll only lose data that was stored in the custom fields or objects that will be deleted when the package is uninstalled. Core CRM objects, like contacts and accounts, will remain intact, even for those records imported from data.com.